# Is possible to train Inception model with entire words?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, ocr

I saw that it is possible to classify characters, like in MNIST model.I am wondering if it is possible to train Inception model on entire words. Let´s consider the scenario that I want to classify if an input image contains a specific word, like HELLO.

First, do you think that it is possible?

If so, how shall we create our training dataset? - taking into consideration that the input image to classify may contain the HELLO world in between other words -.

The other approach, and more logical to me, is to work only on characters, not entire words, but I would like to understand if the approach to work with entire words is possible.

Comment: I have seen models that combine separating words into characters and recognizing them using attention, but can't find it now. You can take a look at this paper, recognizing multidigit numbers https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6082.pdf.